# Question about meaning of "cut the corner"

Tags: word-meaning

Left turns–To make a left turn, drive close to the center divider line or into the left turn lane. Begin signaling about 100 feet before the turn. Look over your left shoulder and reduce your speed. Stop behind the limit line. Look left, then right, then left again, and make the turn when it is safe. When you turn left, do not turn too soon and “**cut the corner**” of the lane belonging to the vehicles coming towards you. Example of a left turn

Could you re write this phrase in simple English?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It can't really get any more simple. When turning left, do not cut across the right lane of the road you are turning into.

Have another diagram - red is wrong, green is correct.

[image]