# What does "rounding a corner" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

What does "rounding a corner" mean in the following paragraph? Does it simply mean [the action of turning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/149445/rounded-the-corner)? If so, I still don't get it.

> "*The idiom, 'cutting corners' was first seen in the 1800s. It is related to rounding a corner instead of taking the proper route.*"
> [Source](https://nosweatshakespeare.com/quotes/famous/cutting-corners/#:%7E:text=The%20idiom%2C%20%E2%80%9Ccutting%20corners%E2%80%9D,sometimes%20backfires%20and%20takes%20longer.)

Comment: You've asked an excellent question, but the bottom line is that the text you're quoting is... unconventional. "Rounding a corner", certainly in British English, means "going round it" without any suggestion of taking a short cut. However, "rounding a corner" in workshop terms /does/ mean reducing its sharpness: which might or might not be desirable. Hence I suggest that the writer you're quoting had his idioms confused.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are asking what "rounding a corner" means **in general**, or "rounding a corner" **in the quoted paragraph**?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should understand there is a *literal* meaning and a *figurative* one.

You've quoted a literal definition. There could well be other applications, but a common one in modern life is in turning in a vehicle at a junction. The link in your question even contains this definition:

> When you come to a sharp turn in the road, instead of going all the way to the corner and then turning, you can go diagonally across, and “cut the corner off”. This saves time, but entails a risk of clipping the kerb and overturning or being involved in a pile-up with another vehicle. Thus “to cut corners” means to discard normal safe practice in order to get fast results.

[image: A car cutting a corner]

This image shows a red car taking the corner correctly, while a dotted line shows a 'corner-cutting' trajectory which is potentially dangerous as it crosses the lane reserved for traffic coming in the other direction.

'Cutting corners' is used in a figurative sense whenever something has been done to save resources (such as time or money) but at the overall expense of another more important measure such as quality. For example, if a builder uses cheaper materials to bring down the cost of a project, but then the building is of poor quality, maybe even structurally compromised as a direct result of the cuts.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! May I ask if in this case "cutting corners" and "rounding a corner" mean the same thing? Thank you all very much once again!

Comment: Quite right that there are both literal and figurative meanings, but the example you show is not at all what I would understand as the literal one (and it's certainly not the figurative one).

Comment: @maurice I've never heard "rounding a corner" said to mean the same as cutting corners. If anything, it sounds like the opposite... in joinery, making a corner edge rounded could be additional finishing work. I think that your quotation is just using the words 'rounding a corner' to help describe what cutting one means. Hopefully the picture I found demonstrates one kind of 'cutting a corner' as well.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Maybe not in your dialect of English, but n British English this is the most literal application of the expression. Figuratively, it tends to refer to cost or time-saving measures at expense of quality. I don't really think it matters what literal example I used to explain - it aptly demonstrates how a curved approach to something instead of taking the corner properly results in a problem.

Comment: [Here's another with another diagram, that fits mine and the other commenters' understanding](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29198/question-about-meaning-of-cut-the-corner) - it's making too sharp a turn, not too wide a turn.

Comment: Ah! I realize here that it is not so much the language that is regionally sensitive, but the image!  For those of us who drive on the right-hand side of the road, the image appears to portray an extra wide turn, not a too-sharp one.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: @Astralbee Thank you once again!

Comment: OP asks "*What does "rounding a corner" mean*", but your answer explains what "cutting corners" means.

Comment: I knew what cutting corners meant, but the car picture confused me. Would something like a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desire_path be a better picture?  https://www.reddit.com/r/DesirePath/comments/pq4547/cutting_corners_in_quebec/

Comment: @CrisLuengo Not if you read it properly, including the title of the question. The quotation given by the OP is a definition of 'cutting corners'. They didn't understand the definition of 'rounding' in relation to that phrase, so I have redefined 'cutting corners' in a way they *do* understand, thereby answering the question. That's why the OP has accepted it.

Comment: @MooingDuck I didn't find any picture on that page helpful but I have since changed the image for one depicting driving on the right because so many people here couldn't seem to grasp the concept of driving on the left as people in 84 countries do.

Comment: Fundamentally, I would associate this with ['cutting through <yards>'](https://www.houzz.com/discussions/6156875/people-cutting-through-backyard-need-ideas-to-help-fix) and not with driving.  Homes on corners sometimes end up with a well-beaten path through their lawn because of kids 'cutting the corner' (as shown in theonlygusti's answer).

Comment: @JohnBollinger That image orientation accounts for my remark as well! Good observation.

Comment: This is a great answer, but the new image offends me.  The turn that extends into the middle of the intersection is actually rounder and faster, but is discouraged by lines on the road, because two opposing cars can't make that kind of turn at the same time in opposite directions.

Answer (score 7):

> What does "rounding a corner" mean in the following paragraph? Does it simply mean the action of turning?

I would ordinarily interpret "rounding a corner" as you say: as *coming around* or *turning* a corner.  This usage is familiar to me.

But from context, the quotation is using it differently, to mean taking a curved route that shortcuts a corner instead of a traveling in a straight line  to the corner, then turning and traveling in a straight line from there.  Possibly the curvedness of the shortcut is not, in fact, important to that expression -- I'm not sure, since it is unfamiliar to me.

In any case, the overall idea of "cutting corners", from which I am inferring the intended meaning of "rounding a corner", is that you do something a little improperly in order to get it done easier or quicker.

Comment: This is my understanding of it as well. "Rounding a corner" simply denotes someone coming around a corner, and doesn't imply either "cutting" the corner or not. If anything, I feel I'd normally expect it in the context of someone walking around the corner of a building, and cutting a corner there would be difficult and/or painful.

Answer (score 4):

No, they don't mean the "turning" or the "circumnavigating" meanings of "rounding". They mean removing the sharp part of the corner so that the corner becomes (more) round. I think a better explanation of the imagery would be:

> taking a shorter or less costly route by not including the whole corner

Comment: [Here](http://mathtourist.blogspot.com/2020/11/cutting-corners.html) is an example.

Answer (score 4):

All 4 permutations of [***to turn/round a/the corner***](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+a+corner) normally mean *begin to find success or improvement after a particularly difficult or troubling period.* The metaphor here relates to ***changing direction*** - compare [***rounded the bend***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22rounded%20the%20bend%22).

That's as opposed to [***cut corners***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-cut-corners) (always plural) = *do something quickly by doing it in a less thorough way than you should.* This metaphoric usage relates to ***taking the shortest / straightest path possible***.

---

I think it's worth mentioning that the *full* (subscription-only) Oxford English Dictionary isn't particularly helpful with their definition of ***to cut corners***. Both literal *and* figurative usages are covered by this single definition...

> 21d **to cut a corner** or **corners**
> to pass round a corner or corners as closely as possible; figurative, to pursue an economical or easy but hazardous course of action; to act in an unorthodox manner to save time; also, to act illegally.

...for which their *first* citation is both ***singular and "literal"...***

> 1869 Mark Twain (Innocents Abroad)
> *He **cuts a corner** so closely now and then..that I feel myself ‘scrooching’, as the children say.*

...but all their other 6 citations (starting with Rudyard Kipling, 1898) are ***plural and figurative***.

---

The phrasing used by OP's cited source is easily understood by native speakers, but anyone who doesn't already know the idiomatic usages - and the fact that the figurative *(use a "quick and dirty" solution)* sense is *always* plural - might find it confusing.

Comment: I think that _cut corners_ is a metaphor for the literal (geometric) act, rather than having any relation to the metaphor in the first paragraph.  Too rushed now to find references, though.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. So far as I'm concerned, the metaphoric allusion in "cutting corners" is to taking a diagonal shortcut rather than going all the way to the corner and then turning 90° to get back as quickly as possible to the "direct, as the crow flies" path towards one's destination.

Comment: Toby means that "cutting corners" and "rounding a corner" are completely unrelated phrases, and your answer makes them sound like they directly relate to each other.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I *really* don't understand that! My answer text is two paragraphs. The first covers all permutations of ***turn/round, a/the***, which are semantically equivalent, and the second (explicitly starting with ***That's as opposed to...***) explains how ***cutting*** corners works. They're only "related" insofar as they're both figurative references to a "path of travel" involving corners, as I'd have thought my text makes crystal clear.

Comment: Ah, I see - you're saying that the the quote in the question is mixing two metaphors.  That it's using "rounding" to really mean "rounding off" the corner rather than _rounding_ as in turning the corner, which is what made me wonder the purpose of that first paragraph.  That's introducing a different metaphor that wasn't asked about and doesn't seem relevant to a question about cutting corners.

Comment: Well, this is a *learners* site. But just because someone doesn't know English very well doesn't mean they need pictures explaining the difference between *literally* using scissors to cut off the sharp corners of a piece of paper, and *metaphorically* anticipating an upcoming corner and moving diagonally to shorten the travel distance. Whereas they probably *do* need to know that the particular cited use of ***rounding a corner*** is actually relatively uncommon...

Comment: ...I'm sure if I analysed all written instances of ***They rounded the corner*** in Google Books, they'd nearly all be for my sense 1 (or for the even more generic sense: *they **came into view** or **gained a better vantage point** after traveling round the corner*). Anyway, apparently I was mistaken - judging by the votes, learners ***do*** need those diagrams! :)

Comment: Upvoted as this is the only answer that includes the metaphorical meaning of "rounding a corner". I think that's a usage that is both common, and hard to figure out if you're just learning English.

Answer (score 3):

instead of walking like this
[image]

you walk like this

[image]